# Is it an issue to use 'code' as column name?

Tags: mysql

This is my query;

```
UPDATE item SET size='0.06' WHERE code='5GT'
```

Yeilds nothing
OR

```
SELECT * from item WHERE code='5GT'
```

Yeilds " MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0007 sec)",

When I know for sure there is a record with code value as 5GT

Comment: And what does this returns ? `WHERE trim(code)= '5GT' `

Comment: Probably a backtick issue as you can see in the answers. Also `code` is not a reserved `MySQL` word so there should be no conflit.

Comment: tried backticks.. didnt work.. tried trim...didnt work tried a similar query on a similar table with code as column name, it worked...except for this table.. f**king strange... 5GT does exist ive checked again and again, even tried this UPDATE item set code=trim(code)... zero rows updated! WTF

Comment: You don't have an item with code '5GT'. If you disagree, please tell us how are you certain that you have?

Comment: Found the SOB! You are half right, there is indeed a code with 5GT problem is there is a new line character which is invisible...i click on edit record and cleared the entire cell and manually keyed in the value so there was no new line.. then queried.. then it worked!! earlier on i had suspected there were trailing spaces so I tried UPDATE item set code=trim(code) but that didnt worked because there is a F**king new line character.. Now how do I get rid of the newline character with a query, because I have over 600 rows to amend

Answer (score 0):

Try this way but cross check first `backtick`character

```
SELECT * from item WHERE trim(code)='5GT'
```